# Porque no puedo acceder a la data en D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

estoy realizando un proyecto para freeCodeCamp en el que necesito hacer una grafica con d3 a partir de una DataBase.
Ya realizae la grafica de barras creando un 'rect' para cada dato y etc. Pero tengo que proceder a agregar un tooltip que me muestre la data de cada barra cuando le pongo el mouseover.

Comparto el codigo que llevo hasta ahora abajo.

https://codepen.io/StayCoold/pen/abPjjQv?editors=0111

Y este es el fragmento donde seguramente tengo el error:

```
const bars = svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(dataset.data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('class','bar')
    .attr('data-date', (d) => d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d")(d[0]))
    .attr('data-gdp', (d) => d[1])
    .attr('x', (d)=> xScale(d[0]))
    .attr('y', (d) => yScale(d[1]) )
    .attr('width', barWidth)
    .attr('height', (d) => h - padding - yScale(d[1]))
    .on('mouseover',(d)=>{d3.select('#tooltip')
                          .html(`data-date: ${bars['data-date']}<br> GDP: ${(d[1])}`)
                           .style('display','block')})
     .on('mouseout',()=>{
       d3.select('#tooltip')
        .style('display','none')
     })
```

Sospecho que aun no comprendo la forma u orden en que compila D3, cualquier ayuda se agradece mucho ya que estoy aprendiendo!

Un abrazo grande.

Comment: Sólo tienes que definir el tooltip antes de usarlo: https://codepen.io/amenadiel/pen/MWZzdGK?editors=1111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola gracias por responder!

si bien el que mencionas no era el problema, lo puede solucionar. Dejo aqui abajo la solucion por si alguien llega a este post en algun momento futuro.

Basicamente, la funcion que se le pasa como argumento a .on, admite dos argumentos. El primero referencia al evento en si y el segundo a la data.

Solucion:

```
.on('mouseover',function(event,d){d3.select('#tooltip')
                          .html(`data-date: ${d[0]}<br> GDP: ${(d[1])}`)
                           .style('display','block')})
```